# "without you are/your being/being seen"

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I construct sentences like **a)** and **b)** below, instead of **c)**? I understand the construction in c) is the most common and acceptable one.

- **a)** Try to deliver the gifts without you are seen.
- **b)** Try to deliver the gifts without your being seen.
- **c)** Try to deliver the gifts without being seen.

Answer (score 2):

a) is not grammatical in most varieties of English : *without* introduces a noun phrase or an *ing* clause, not a finite clause. (There are some dialects which allow it, I think, but no standard varieties).

b) is grammatical, but unusual: we usually don't express the subject of a subordinate clause when it's the same as the (actual or implied) subject of the matrix sentence.

Note also that, while the possessive *your being* is what the traditional grammar books say, many people now don't use it, and would say *We'll go in the back way so we can get in without **you** being seen.* (I've used a different sentence in which the *you(r)* is more natural). *Your being* is certainly not wrong, but some people would regard it as very formal.

Comment: Much appreciated. Why is exactly the 'a' not grammatical? How would you like to construct the sentence if you required to keep the clause 'you are seen' in the 'a'?

Comment: @Airforce: I have answered that. _Without_ in most varieties of English cannot take a finite clause. If you want to retain _you re seen_ you'll have to use a long paraphrase like _in a way that avoids the possibility that you are seen_ (because _possibility_ can take a "that" clause). A shorter alternative would be _in a way that you are not seen_, which does not preserve the sequence _you are seen_, but still has a finite clase.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's now understood. The 'without' is similar to how we use the 'despite', for example, in a sentence.

Comment: Exactly. _Without_ and _despite_ are prepositions, unlike (for example) _unless_, which is a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: Much appreciated. Lastly, could I have written the sentence, like "Try to deliver the gifts without anyone('s) seeing you." ?

Comment: Yes, you could, @Airforce. Again, most people would say _anyone_, but the traditional grammar books say it should be _anyone's_. In this case, the difference is hardly audible.

Comment: @ColinFine How about "Try to deliver the gifts without you being seen."? Is it grammatical?

Comment: @StatsCruncher: see my second and third paragraphs. It's grammatical (except for the sticklers who insist it should be _without your being seen_); but it's unlikely to be said, because "you" is implied